# Job Scheduler service not work when app is killed

Tags: android, android-service

I'm working on an android app which requires a background task to be performed every hour(Job Scheduler or Service). Task gets executed when the app is running but as soon as I kill the app from foreground, service not work. Is there another way to achieve this?

**1. Service**

```
public class NotificationService extends JobService {

    private void PrintLog()
    {
        Log.d("DGVCL", "PrintLog()");
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onStartJob(JobParameters jobParameters) {
        Log.d("DGVCL", "onStartJob()");
        PrintLog();
        jobFinished(jobParameters, false);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onStopJob(JobParameters jobParameters) {
        Log.d("DGVCL", "onStopJob()");
        return true;
    }
}
```

**2. Main Activity**

```
JobScheduler jobScheduler = (JobScheduler)getApplicationContext().getSystemService(JOB_SCHEDULER_SERVICE);
        ComponentName componentName = new ComponentName(this, NotificationService.class);
        JobInfo jobInfo = new JobInfo.Builder(1, componentName)
                .setPeriodic(Global.NOTIFICATION_TIME_PERIOD)
                .setBackoffCriteria(Global.NOTIFICATION_TIME_PERIOD, JobInfo.BACKOFF_POLICY_LINEAR)
                .setPersisted(true).build();
        jobScheduler.schedule(jobInfo);
```

**3. manifest**

```
<service android:name="com.hopesndreams.hiren.hd.service.NotificationService" android:permission="android.permission.BIND_JOB_SERVICE" >
    </service>
```

Comment: use work manager , its stable now and its better

Comment: as per latest android version's you can only run foreground service

Comment: What device you tested on ?

Comment: @ManoharReddy can you provide any example.

Comment: @hirenpatel don't ask if people can provide examples before reading first. https://developer.android.com/guide/background

Comment: @MaksimNovikov im testing on POCO F1. this code works fine in older version of android.

Comment: check https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/android-workmanager

Comment: @hirenpatel That is the problem you use Xiaomi, i have xiaomi mi 6 and have same issues with WorkManager and JobSchedular, the only thing that works after app kill is AlarmManager

Comment: JobScheduler actully never worked for me with app killed. I was forced to switch to old AlarmManger, which is tested and widely used.

Comment: @MaksimNovikov I have tried that AlarmManager also but that is also not working when I kill app.

Comment: I have also the similar issue. When my application is alive then only WorkManager working well but when my application closed the Workmanager also closed or not working.

Answer (score 0):

Use WorkManager it is build on top of JobScheduler and it is specifically build to take on all background services both foreground and background functionalities. https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/workmanager

Comment: Even though google promise to handle all scheduled tasks with work manager i can say for sure that it depends on device manufacturer, for example on my xioami device work manager wont work after app get killed on other phones it work.

Comment: @MaksimNovikov What will be the better solution which fulfils all the needs off the device ?

Comment: The only thing i know still works fine for all devices is the old and good AlarmManager

Comment: ^ note that scheduled alarms are cleared when the device reboots

Comment: @SureshPeriyasamy did you come up with any solution? as im still stuck and nothing is working for me.

Comment: @hirenpatel In WorkManager there is option called PeriodicWorkRequest which has minimum time of 15 minutes it works .Try and see Source - https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/work/PeriodicWorkRequest

Answer (score 0):

> *** Using AlarmManager***
>
> Step 1:Create a ***Service***

Do your Logic here in the service

```
        public class AService extends Service {

        @Override
        public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
            //do something
        }

        @Override
        public void onCreate() {
            //do somrthing
        }
    }
```

> Step 2: Create a BroadCast receiver

Start your service with this.

```
        public class AReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
            try {
                Intent intent = new Intent(context, AService.class);
                context.startService(intent);
            } catch (Exception e) {
            }
        }
    }
```

> in MainActivity

```
   Intent liveIntent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), AReceiver.class);
    PendingIntent recurring = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(getApplicationContext(), 0, liveIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT);
    AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
    Calendar updateTime = Calendar.getInstance();
    alarmManager.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, updateTime.getTimeInMillis(), 16 * 60 * 1000, recurring);
    //wakeup and starts service in every 16 minutes.
```

This is the method working for me. Works fine even if you close the app. Works in Xiaomi devices.

> Don't forget to add the service inside the manifest

Comment: Beware because AlarmManager alarms are erased if you turn off your phone

Answer (score 0):

Indeed, WorkManager is the way to go.

You can read up more on other work primitives to suit your task [here](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/workmanager/advanced/threading), but the below implementation uses Worker for threading in WorkManager, which performs work synchronously on a background thread.

```
public class BackgroundWorker extends Worker {

    public BackgroundWorker
            (@NonNull Context context,
             @NonNull WorkerParameters params) {
             super(context, params);
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override

    public Worker.Result doWork() {     
        yourBackgroundTask();  // yourBackgroundTask() implementation
        return Result.success();
    }

    public static void schedulePeriodicWork(Data data) {
        // When multiple constraints are specified like below, 
        // your task will run only when all the constraints are met.
        Constraints constraints = new Constraints.Builder()
                        .setRequiredNetworkType(NetworkType.CONNECTED)
                        .setRequiresBatteryNotLow(true)
                        .setRequiresCharging(true)
                        .build();

        PeriodicWorkRequest taskWork = new PeriodicWorkRequest.Builder(BackgroundWorker.class, 60,
                TimeUnit.MINUTES)
                .setConstraints(constraints)
                .setInputData(data)
                .build();

        WorkManager.getInstance().enqueue(taskWork);
    } 
}
```

Later in your MainActivity file, inside `onCreate()`:

```
Data data = workData();

BackgroundWorker.schedulePeriodicWork(data);
```

Then outside the `onCreate()` method,

```
private Data workData() {
    return new Data.Builder() // to build Data objects
        .build();
}
```

One small thing to note, is that though we set the above task to execute every 60 minutes, each iteration may not be executed at the same time interval.

According to Android documentation, WorkManager is meant for deferrable work, and some drift must be tolerated. However, you can check your log console for the update, "`WM-WorkerWrapper: Worker result SUCCESS for Work`".

Hope this is helpful.

Comment: I try to use this but, dowork method call only once. for testing i set periodic time 20 second but it's not work.

Comment: minimum is 15 minutes